# python : what's with my xpath expression ? 3

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to extract information from a web site using Python lxml and xpath and I'm getting a error with this xpath expression What's the problem of my xpath expression

```
//*[@id="kaymu"]/div[4]/div[11]/article/a/section[1]/h3/text()
```

Comment: what error? ...

Comment: post url and the error message

Comment: Never tell us you are getting an error without telling us what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

we won't be able to know what's wrong with your xpath if you do not provide the html or the error.

however, i would like to offer an alternative xpath that should work if the error is really with the xpath and not because the element is not visible:
`//*[@id="kaymu"]/div[4]/div[11]//section[1]/h3/text()`

if the error is that the element is not visible, try waiting first for the page to load before you look for the element.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15136857)

Comment: there you go ive answered it